# Looking for a word meaning "run over by a wheel"

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word meaning "run over by a wheel".

My first though was something like:

`... as the body is trampled by the wagon wheels ...`

but in my mind, trample is really something under foot, people walking over, not run over by wheels.

My mind is nagging me for a simple word the seems just beyond my grasp, so I thought I'd reach out for any ideas.

Thoughts?

Comment: Crushed, but not wheel-specific

Comment: I was **rutted**...

Comment: "Steamrolled" applies to one specific type of wheel...

Comment: I think "trampled" carries the meaning better than the other choices.

Comment: *Scythed.*  A narrow wheel can cut as well as crush.

Answer (score 1):

As in:

> ... as the body is **crushed** by the wagon wheels ...

to **crush**

> to press between opposing bodies so as to break or compress

[TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/crush)